# Change password module in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone please help me? I'm stuck in this code for a couple of days already. I hope someone could help me..

My problem is if old password is correct and the new password and re-enter password didn't match it still changes the password in the database..

this is my controller:

```
 public function changepwd(){
  $this->load->view('changepassword'); // this is my view
  $this->load->helper('security');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('opassword','Old Password','required|trim|callback_change["empID"]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('npassword','New Password','required|trim');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confirm Password','required|trim|matches[npassword]');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

    echo validation_errors("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>","</div>");

  }

}

public function change($id){
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $query=$this->db->query("select * FROM employee WHERE empID= " .$this->session->userdata('empID'));

  foreach ($query->result() as $my_info) {
      $db_password = $my_info->password;
      $db_id = $my_info->empID; 
  }

  if((md5($this->input->post('opassword', $db_password)) == $db_password) && ($this->input->post('npassword') != '') && ($this->input->post('cpassword')!='')) { 

      $fixed_pw = md5($this->input->post('npassword'));
      $update = $this->db->query("Update employee SET password='$fixed_pw' WHERE empID='$db_id'")or die(mysql_error()); 
      $this->form_validation->set_message('change','<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
      <strong>Password Updated!</strong></div>');

  } else {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('change','<div class="alert alert-error"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
      <strong>Wrong Old Password!</strong> </div>');

  }    
}
```

Comment: Just a question, but have you got a good reason for embedding your own SQL rather than using [CodeIgniter's query builder class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
md5($this->input->post('opassword', $db_password)) == $db_password)
  && ($this->input->post('npassword') != '')
  && ($this->input->post('cpassword') != '')
```

The first line checks that old password is correct. The second two lines check if that new and confirmed passwords are not empty.

Try adding a term that checks that the passwords are also equal:

```
... && ($this->input->post('npassword') == $this->input->post('cpassword'))
```

Might work.

There are other things that worry me with your code. But that's another story. (Read about SQL injections, the MVC pattern and how to safely store user passwords in a database)